# Kafka Streams - Offset commit failed. The request timed out

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am getting

> Offset commit failed on partition app-KSTREAM-MAP-0000000017-repartition-2 at offset 2768614: The request timed out.

I have already increased the request timeout to 1 minute but it didn't help. I am using versions:

- spring-kafka: 2.1.12.RELEASE
- kafka-clients, kafka-streams: 2.1.1
- kafka_2.11: 2.1.1

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the batch size `ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG`

Also look at tuning these

- `ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG`
- `ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG`